# cucumber selenium not setting values in angular js webapp

Tags: angularjs, selenium, cucumber

I am putting together a small training webapp for my company to experiment with TDD methodologies.  I am so new to angular js not sure why my cucumber selenium is not finding the right element and inserting proper values.
Hoping someone can slap me upside the head and tell me what I am missing

My Feature file

```
  Scenario: Add two positive numbers
  Given I am on the demo page
  When I add the numbers 2 and 3
  Then the result is 5
```

my web page has the following div

```
 <div class="well well-lg text-center" ng-controller="additionController">
    <h2>Addition</h2>
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">First Number: </label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input id="adder-first-number" class="form-control" ng-model="firstNumber" type="text"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Second Number: </label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input id="adder-second-number" class="form-control" ng-model="secondNumber" type="text"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button id="adder-button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" ng-click="add()">Add</button>
        </div>
    </form>


        <span id="adder-result" style="font-size: 500%">{{additionResult}}</span>
  </div>
```

Running maven verify  I am getting

```
  2017-03-13 16:00:10.867 plugin-container[2745:390865] *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0x513f, name = 'com.apple.tsm.portname'
See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.
 2017-03-13 16:00:10.869 plugin-container[2745:390865] *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0x501b, name = 'com.apple.CFPasteboardClient'
        See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.
2017-03-13 16:00:10.869 plugin-container[2745:390865] void __CFPasteboardSetup() : Failed to allocate communication port for com.apple.CFPasteboardClient; this is likely due to sandbox restrictions
!!!!!!!! x=2 y=3
>>>>>>>>first number=2 y=3

  Scenario: Add two positive numbers # net/xeric/demos/adder.feature:3
   Given I am on the demo page      # DemoSteps.i_am_on_the_demo_page()
   When I add the numbers 2 and 3   #  DemoSteps.i_add_the_numbers_and(int,int)
  org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: #adder\-first\-number
  For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
  Build info: version: '3.2.0', revision: '8c03df6b79', time: '2017-02-23 10:51:31 +0000'
  System info: host: 'Peters-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:22c9:d0ff:fe44:908d%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.6', java.version: '1.8.0_101'
  Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
  Capabilities [{moz:profile=/var/folders/2m/csls0wzx7mnfx5s83c_d47bm0000gn/T/rust_mozprofile.K71LPcrDJ8Gw, rotatable=false, timeouts={implicit=0, page load=300000, script=30000}, pageLoadStrategy=normal, platform=ANY, specificationLevel=0, moz:accessibilityChecks=false, acceptInsecureCerts=false, browserVersion=52.0, platformVersion=15.6.0, moz:processID=2740, browserName=firefox, platformName=darwin}]
  Session ID: 304ff3e9-59b4-a74f-8386-499bdc5318c3
  *** Element info: {Using=id, value=adderfirstnumber}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:127)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:93)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:42)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:163)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:604)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:371)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementById(RemoteWebDriver.java:420)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:218)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:363)
    at net.xeric.demos.pages.DemoPage.addNumbers(DemoPage.java:33)
    at net.xeric.demos.steps.DemoSteps.i_add_the_numbers_and(DemoSteps.java:35)
    at ✽.When I add the numbers 2 and 3(net/xeric/demos/adder.feature:5)
```

my step file  has the following clearly from the output above the args are 2 and 3

```
    @When("^I add the numbers (-?\\d+) and (-?\\d+)$")
public void i_add_the_numbers_and(int arg1, int arg2) throws Throwable     {
    System.out.println("!!!!!!!! x=" + arg1 + " y=" + arg2);
    demoPage.addNumbers(arg1, arg2);
}
```

the DemoPage.java has

```
 public void addNumbers(int x, int y) {
    System.out.println(">>>>>>>>first number=" + x + " y="+y);
    driver.findElement(By.id("adder-first-number")).sendKeys(Integer.toString(x));
    driver.findElement(By.id("adder-second-number")).sendKeys(Integer.toString(y));
    driver.findElement(By.id("adder-button")).click();
 }
```

JUST realized FF screen had this flash for a quick second.  What does this mean?

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Tue Mar 14 08:36:47 PDT 2017
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

Comment: First try to verify that the form elements are visible or not and then use sendKeys if they are visible.

Comment: Is the `form` inside a frame?

Comment: how do I determine if the form elements are visible?

Comment: the individual div's are not within a frame tag

Comment: expect(element('#some-id:visible').count()).toBe(1);   shows visibility??? can that be put into java step file?

Answer (score 0):

the problem appears to be Firefox selenium related. I was able to get it all working when using chrome and chrome driver.   Some day I'll go back and see if I can get it to work in FF, IE, Safari

Comment: once I upgrade to selenium 3.3.1 and found all the correct webdrivers it all works